# JSP/Tomcat development: Does intellij idea automatically move packages to web-inf folder?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am having a problem with errors such as:

```
    HTTP Status 500 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 9 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. com.test.util.ConnectionManager resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 31 in the jsp file: /test.jsp
EmployeeDAO cannot be resolved to a type
28:                 <td>Job Title</td>
29:                 <td>Hire Date</td>
30:             </tr>
31:             <%  EmployeeDAO em = new EmployeeDAO();
32:             Connection ct = ConnectionManager.getInstance().getConnection();
33:             ResultSet rs = em.selectByFirstNameRS(empN,ct);
34:             try {


An error occurred at line: 31 in the jsp file: /test.jsp
EmployeeDAO cannot be resolved to a type
28:                 <td>Job Title</td>
29:                 <td>Hire Date</td>
30:             </tr>
31:             <%  EmployeeDAO em = new EmployeeDAO();
32:             Connection ct = ConnectionManager.getInstance().getConnection();
33:             ResultSet rs = em.selectByFirstNameRS(empN,ct);
34:             try {


An error occurred at line: 32 in the jsp file: /test.jsp
ConnectionManager cannot be resolved
29:                 <td>Hire Date</td>
30:             </tr>
31:             <%  EmployeeDAO em = new EmployeeDAO();
32:             Connection ct = ConnectionManager.getInstance().getConnection();
33:             ResultSet rs = em.selectByFirstNameRS(empN,ct);
34:             try {
35:                     if(rs != null) {%>


An error occurred at line: 53 in the jsp file: /test.jsp
ConnectionManager cannot be resolved
50:             } catch (Exception e) {
51:                 e.printStackTrace();
52:             } finally {
53:                 ConnectionManager.getInstance().releaseConnection(ct);
54:             }%>
55:         </table>
56:             <a href="index.html">Return to search</a>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.33 logs.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/6.0.33
```

I was looking through google and it may be caused by not having packages inside the WEB-INF folder. I am running `tomcat` through `IntelliJ` IDEA and I'm wondering shouldn't it move  packages that are already in the filepath to the created `WEB-INF` folder on its own? And if it does, what am I doing wrong? This is the two files I'm using:

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <title>Employee Test Webapp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Employee Database:</h3>
    <table>
        <tr>
            What is the name of the Employee you want to find?
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <form action="test.jsp" method="post">
            <td><input type="text" name="empName"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="search"></td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

And test.jsp:

```
<%@ page import="com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.writer.document.xsd.Import" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="com.test.dao.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@ page import="com.test.util.ConnectionManager" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>
<% String empN = request.getParameter("empName"); %>
<html>
<head><title>Employee Test Web App</title></head>
<body>
        Your results are:

        <table cellpadding="15" border="1" style="background-color: #ffffcc;">
            <tr>
                <td>Employee ID</td>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td>Company Name</td>
                <td>Department Name</td>
                <td>Job Title</td>
                <td>Hire Date</td>
            </tr>
            <%  EmployeeDAO em = new EmployeeDAO();
            Connection ct = ConnectionManager.getInstance().getConnection();
            ResultSet rs = em.selectByFirstNameRS(empN,ct);
            try {
                    if(rs != null) {%>
                        <%while (rs.next()) {%>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%=rs.getInt(1)%></td>
                            <td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
                            <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
                            <td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td>
                            <td><%=rs.getString(5)%></td>
                            <td><%=rs.getString(6)%></td>
                            <td><%=rs.getString(7)%></td>
                        </tr><%
                        }
                    }else{
                        %> <tr>Table empty</tr> <%
                    }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                ConnectionManager.getInstance().releaseConnection(ct);
            }%>
        </table>
            <a href="index.html">Return to search</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Some imports Idea made on its own. Here's my filepath:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJqQq.png

Please help.

Comment: I have not used Intellij and Tomcat together. But I do not believe that this is the problem with the IDE. To check it, can you click on Build -> Build "Test.war" exploded artifact. Now there would be an out folder in your proj directory. Open that folder to see if the class files made it to the artifact.

Comment: The Out folder has 3 subfolders: artifacts, production and test. The classes are under test. Is that where they should be?

Comment: If you had created the war file, under artifact, there should be an exploded war file. Under the war file, look for classes under web_inf. If it does not work, come in chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project Structure was right and intellij took care of everything. The resolve error was product of an inner runtime error that had to be corrected first. I used the tomcat logs in order to find it. Thanks for all your help either way.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see the contents of your WAR file or exploded WAR directory.

Normally IntelliJ does copy everything in the build path to the appropriate place in the WAR but sometimes and for some file types it doesn't always notice changes. In this case, that shouldn't be an issue because it is a class file. I think it is also strange that it thinks com.test.util.ConnectionManager is a package.

My suggestion would be to make sure your stop tomcat before doing a Build All and, when that doesn't help (because I really don't think it will) check the settings for your WAR artifact and make sure it is pulling in all the right files.

Comment: I posted a link to a picture of the project structure on the original, but here it is again: http://i.imgur.com/iJd8H.png

Comment: hope this helps also: http://i.imgur.com/eZ9ED.png artifact under project structure

Comment: You need to see what is actually in the generated WAR file or exploded WAR directory that is being deployed to tomcat. From your second screen shot, it looks like that should be in Test\out\artifacts\Test_war_exploded after you do a build.